# cannot find Java desktop application option

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop

I cannot find java desktop application option under the java section in create new project wizard.
can anyone help?

i want to create a java desktop application and looking at the various tutorials all they say is select java desktop application from under java in new project wizard. but i don't have that option. please help

Comment: Hmmm even I couldn't find anything named exactly as Java desktop application !

Comment: I think this will light some shade on what you are looking for [Java Application vs. Java Desktop Application in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097706/java-application-vs-java-desktop-application-in-netbeans). If you have Netbeans version higher than 7.0, then that option has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no such an option. Just create new Java application project.

File > New Project > Under categories select Java > Java Application

If you want to create new JFrame/JPanel/JInternalFrame/JDialog:

Right click on desired package > New > Other > Under categories select Swing GUI forms > And choose component you want.

Comment: They use to have that option in Netbeans until 7.0