# How to create a Java Desktop Application in NetBeans IDE 7.2.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsr296

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I find Java desktop application in Netbeans 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146976/why-cant-i-find-java-desktop-application-in-netbeans-7-1)

I used to have the option to create a new "Java Desktop Application" in Netbeans 6.9.1. However, I can't find this option any longer in NetBeans IDE 7.2.1.

Is it still available?

Comment: What does it mean create java application in netbeans?

Comment: As an alternative to Swing, you can also try the new [JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) support in conjunction with [Scene Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/overview/jsbpub-overview.htm) to build a JavaFX desktop application.

Comment: I would urge folks not to close this question.  There have been new developments not covered in the potential duplicate cited by @assylias.

Comment: @Gene What developments? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Please see my answer below.  The SAF mechanism was dropped, then resurected as BSAF, then killed again by removing SAF from the wizard and form editor, but then recently a plug-in was published that made it feasible to use again.

Answer (score 1):

The party line from the Netbeans project contributors is to use the [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html).  In the wizard look under Netbeans Modules.

The Swing Application Framework (SAF) that you're probably remembering has been abandoned.

Netbeans Platform seems reasonably good, but it represents a fairly big effort to learn its conventions and capabilties.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146976/why-cant-i-find-java-desktop-application-in-netbeans-7-1) talks about [BSAF](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home), which is some level of continued support for SAF.  However BSAF took a hit when Netbeans dropped the wizard and  form edit capabilities that are part of SAF.  The most recent development is [the return of SAF/BSAF form editing as a plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43853/swing-application-framework-support) for the v7+ Netbeans environments.  You can no longer generate a SAF/BSAF app with the app wizard.  A workaround is to make a SAF application in 6.9.1 and then import it as needed to make new ones in 7.2+.