# NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I developed a Java Swing Application. It was developed using Netbeans in OSX. It runs perfectly in nix but when it comes to windows, I get this exception:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property

Tried many things like removing and adding libs to the class path again. Googled a lot in vein. How can I fix it?

Problem partially solved. Built the same project in windows and its working in windows. The jar built in nix works fine in nix but shows this error in windows.

Answer (score 3):

Unix (and OSX) have different classpath separator than windows (`:` instead of `;`), check out your startup script or command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

AS you have already mentioned, issue is with the missing jar file in class path.

Try printing the java class path from code and look out for the missing jar file.

System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Answer (score 0):

`org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Property` is part of [jsr296](/questions/tagged/jsr296), which no longer supported in newer versions of NetBeans. See [*Why can't I find Java desktop application in Netbeans 7.1*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9146976/261156) for more.

Answer (score -1):

Once I had the same problem but not with swings with jdbc. I tried a lot and got the solution.
First you make sure that all things said in google and the above answers are done. Still if the problem persists means delete all the class files created before and rerun the project once again, it ll work.  Notify me if it works.