# I want to create a Desktop Application in Net beans based on Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

## I want to make a Desktop Application in Net Beans.

Please help me as i am new to Net Beans to start developing a **Java based Desktop Application**.

I have Net Beans 7.1 but i cant find any feature which can help me start making a Desktop Application.

I found this below a bit link useful but my Net Beans IDE does not have any option under 
Java as Java Desktop Application

http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2009/08/making-executable-desktop-application.html

Comment: Make sure your versions match with the ones in the tutorial. There are a lot of version out there. Also check plugins

Comment: google for javafx  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/

Answer (score 3):

You are using 7.1 and the tutorial is for 6.1.

The menu has changed, the reason: [Why can't I find Java desktop application in Netbeans 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146976/why-cant-i-find-java-desktop-application-in-netbeans-7-1)

But it doesn't really matter that much, at least in your case, just select `Java > Java Application`. You'll still have a GUI that will allow you to create windows and components by using your mouse.

For the purpose of learning, I recommend that you install the old Netbeans, so that you can follow the tutorial. As you gain knowledge, you'll be able to figure out things by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

no need to take java desktop application,
create a java application, then you can create GUI in it

Answer (score 0):

I have got an atleast start to my Question thanks to all who have commented & answered , still searching further to get something better.

**This link helped me:**
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html